# How to load ressources with cookie from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, resources

I want to serve some content to authenticated users only. (**script**, **img**, etc...)

To do so, I set cookie to check the credentials.

The issue is when I try to access those ressources browser do not send the cookie.
Fetch does send the request cookie but nothing from **HTML**.

In my **HTML** I have:

```
<script src="/assets/protected.js"></script>
```

In the debugger I can copy the request as **fetch** to see that credentials is set to **omit**.

```
fetch(
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/protected.js",
    {
        "credentials":"omit","headers":{},
        "referrer":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/",
        "referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade",
        "body":null,
        "method":"GET",
        "mode":"cors"
    }
);
```

Is there a way to send **cookies** on requests from **HTML**?

Comment: By default, every request to the same host:port contains all cookies. How are you intercepting the serving of static files server-side?

Comment: You are right.

The cookie should be send. When I build a fresh server client send cookie.

I need to do a deep check on what happens.

Thank you and sorry for this...

Comment: My issue is from a custom dynamic load of the scripts inside a full AJAX website and the issue is from there.

Sorry for the noise and my poor analyze before asking for answers.

Comment: AJAX or not doesn't matter; whether you use `$.load()`, `$.ajax()` or `someScriptElement.src = "path/to/script.js"`, as long as the resource is on the same server/port, all cookies get sent along. Checking cookies before serving a static file, whether served upon opening a page or requested via AJAX, requires intercepting the serving of static files *server-side*. Most web servers by default just send the file over as-is if the requested resource exists as file, so unless you prevent that, you cannot check for cookies when a *.js file is requested.

Comment: I put scripts inside the **HTML** after the initial load.
When I change content in my body the scripts present in the new **HTML** content are not loaded.
To load them scripts I made an other script which build a new script element. I was setting the **src** attribut and add it to the body. This way the cookie was not sent.

I made it differently by downloading the file with **fetch** and loading scripts by setting the **innerHTML** of the elements before putting them into the body.

This solved my issue which was specific, because of my resource management.

Sorry about this...

Comment: `To load them scripts I made an other script which build a new script element. I was setting the src attribut and add it to the body. This way the cookie was not sent.` I simply cannot confirm this at all. When I do the exact same thing, the cookies get sent along just fine. Why do you think they are not getting sent along for you?

Comment: I will try to make a docker image with it sources to let you test this if you like.
By the way I'm on Arch Linux with Chromium. It's maybe related to the platform.

Comment: I made a [Docker image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MUe4c9nKInLKGMGcisuzIqP5emhXDSma/view?usp=sharing) which expose the issue. This is a tar with all sources and the docker image ready to load to a Docker daemon.
In fact if you set the **type** attribut to **module** the cookies are not sent. That's why in my example two scripts are downloaded.